# Uncompressing different types (zip, tar.gz, etc) of archive files in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a module or a rubygem that automatically recognizes specific archive type and extract them to a specific folder?
I saw that libarchive seems to do this but I can't find how to extract to a specific folder.

Comment: There's an awful lot of compression formats out there, each of which has specific dependencies. Supporting them all is a non-trivial sort of thing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While we'd like to help you, your question is pretty broad and can't be reduced to a concise answer. What have you tried? Have you written code and encountered a problem or are you looking for documentation before you start? Can you reduce your question to a specific library? Are you ignoring everything but libarchive?